# Select column from first and last record matching criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the following table in an application which deals with scheduling of assets:

```
date       group_id  free_spots
2011-01-01   1         0
2011-01-01   2         0
2011-01-08   1         1
2011-01-08   2         0
2011-01-15   1         1
2011-01-15   2         1
2011-01-22   1         2
2011-01-22   2         2
2011-01-29   1         1
2011-01-29   2         0
2011-02-05   1         0
2011-02-05   2         1
2011-02-12   1         0
2011-02-12   2         1
2011-02-19   1         0
2011-02-19   2         0
```

This information is put together using a fairly expensive query (~100ms) using different tables. The result can either be put into a temp table, or used directly inline.

What I want is to find the first date which offers a spot (free_spots > 0). Then in the same record I want the last date which offsers a spot. All of this grouped by the group_id.

To illustrate, on the given example table, I would expect the following output:

```
group_id  start_date  end_date
1         2011-01-08  2011-01-29
2         2011-01-15  2011-01-22
2         2011-02-05  2011-02-12
```

Now, I already came up with a rough solution. Using the given table I would:

- Grab all records which are preceded* by either NULL or a record with free_spots <= 0 (start date)
- For all these records, grab the first successor* that is succeeded by a row being NULL or having free_spots <= 0
- Somehow mixing the grouping by group_id in here.

However, this seems impossible as I cannot use the same subquery again to find successors or preceding records. Same deal with temporary tables. These I cannot open and re-use more than once.

( * Preceded or succeeded is based on the date. For each group, the dates are equal, sequential and evenly (but arbitrarily) spaced. Usually 7 or 14 days)

Comment: Please see my update that has the start of a MySQL translation for my working SQL Server answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be super efficient, but it works on your data.  (Note that I added a WHERE constraint for a date range if you want one):

```
SELECT group_id,MIN(`date`) AS start_date,
       (SELECT `date` FROM Slots s3 
        WHERE s3.group_id=t.group_id 
        AND s3.`date`<t.next_stop_date
        AND s3.free_spots > 0
        ORDER BY s3.`date`DESC
        LIMIT 1) as end_date
FROM 
  (SELECT s1.*, MIN(s2.`date`) AS next_stop_date 
   FROM 
     Slots s1 LEFT JOIN Slots s2 
       ON s2.`date` > s1.date AND s1.group_id=s2.group_ID AND s2.free_spots = 0
   WHERE s1.free_spots > 0 
   GROUP BY s1.group_id, s1.`date`
   ORDER BY s1.group_id ASC, s1.`date` ASC
  ) AS t
GROUP BY group_id, next_stop_date
```

Comment: Sadly this seems to give the same error I ran into with my attempts: Can't reopen table 's3'. Also, any reason those dates are hardcoded in your query? I assume I could omit those as well to process the entire table?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "can't reopen table `s3`".  You can remove the dates without affecting anything.  (I just edited the answer so that they are not longer there.)

Comment: You can check out the data and play with the query at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0f4b5/12/0

Comment: The 'problem' was in the 'Spots' table, which is a temporary table. Even if I make it an inline query, it is still based on at least one other temp table. Temp tables can only be opened once, which causes said error.

I have solved it quick and dirty by cloning Spots into 3 separate temp tables and using each one where appropriate in your query. 

This causes your query to work neatly and get the information I need. I am going to accept your answer as the correct one. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help.  Good luck with the rest of your project.

Answer (score 1):

I can write this in SQL Server, and know it's translatable to MySQL. First I will give you the SQL Server version, then give you a boost on the translation below. I would have skipped the question but did not realize at first that it was for MySQL.

This tolerates variable gaps of any length between dates.

```
WITH IDs AS (
   SELECT *, Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY GroupID ORDER BY AvailableDate) ID
   FROM Availability
), Data AS (
   SELECT
      GroupID,
      AvailableDate,
      ID - Dense_Rank() OVER (PARTITION BY GroupID ORDER BY ID) G
   FROM IDs
   WHERE FreeSpots > 0
)
SELECT
   GroupID,
   Min(AvailableDate) FromDate,
   Max(AvailableDate) ToDate
FROM Data
GROUP BY GroupID, G;
```

Here's the setup script:

```
CREATE TABLE Availability (
   AvailableDate datetime,
   GroupID tinyint,
   FreeSpots tinyint
)
INSERT Availability
SELECT '20110101', 1, 0
UNION ALL SELECT '20110101', 2, 0
UNION ALL SELECT '20110108', 1, 1
UNION ALL SELECT '20110108', 2, 0
UNION ALL SELECT '20110115', 1, 1
UNION ALL SELECT '20110115', 2, 1
UNION ALL SELECT '20110122', 1, 2
UNION ALL SELECT '20110122', 2, 2
UNION ALL SELECT '20110129', 1, 1
UNION ALL SELECT '20110129', 2, 0
UNION ALL SELECT '20110205', 1, 0
UNION ALL SELECT '20110205', 2, 1
UNION ALL SELECT '20110212', 1, 0
UNION ALL SELECT '20110212', 2, 1
UNION ALL SELECT '20110219', 1, 0
UNION ALL SELECT '20110219', 2, 0
```

**MySQL Translation**

The following should be equivalent to my first CTE (Common Table Expression), simulating the Row_Number() function. With a little tweaking, you can use this as a derived table for doing the second CTE to simulate Dense_Rank(), and you have a working query!

```
SELECT
   GroupID,
   AvailableDate,
   FreeSpots,
   @rownum=CASE WHEN @grpset <> GroupID THEN 0 ELSE @rownum + 1 END AS rownum,
   @grpset=GroupID AS grpset
FROM
   (SELECT @grpset= -1) g,
   (SELECT @rownum:= -1) r,
   (SELECT *
    FROM Availability
    ORDER BY GroupID, AvailableDate
   ) a
```

I know MySQL not one tiny bit, so am cribbing from an example online. This *should* work, but I could have let a syntax error slip in there. If this query works and you want more help, let me know and I'll try to work it up into the full query for MySQL. Though if @Quassnoi shows up, you'll have it in no time at all!

Comment: Thanks for your input. Im sorry I wasn't more clear on using MySQL. I appreciate your answer but I am going with Holger Brandt's solution, as it operates directly on the data and is more logical to me. If I run into trouble I will attempt your solution.

Comment: You were clear but it was edited out of the title. I would never advise anyone to use MySQL for reasons like what you just pointed out... very sad.

Answer (score 0):

The query is not very good but seems work:

```
SELECT *
FROM (

SELECT a.group_id, a.`date` AS
start_date , max( b.`date` ) AS
end_date
FROM test AS a
LEFT JOIN test AS b ON a.group_id = b.group_id
AND b.free_spots >0
AND a.date < b.date
WHERE a.free_spots >0
AND (

SELECT count( * )
FROM test AS c
WHERE c.group_id = a.group_id
AND c.date > a.date
AND c.date < b.date
AND free_spots =0
) =0
GROUP BY group_id,
start_date
) AS d
WHERE end_date IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY d.end_date
ORDER BY `d`.`group_id` ASC
```

Answer (score -1):

I can't think of a super easy way to do this. Here's a sketch of one way I can think of it (using multiple queries)

`create temporary table temp1 select group_id,min(date) as start_date from table1 where free_spots>0 group by group_id`

`alter table temp1 add column end_date datetime default null`

`create temporary table`temp2`select * from table1 where free_spots>0`

Then in a while loop (using some programming language), I would do the following until temp2 is empty. You should increment the date to the next day at each step in the loop (call it $curDate):

`update temp2,temp1 set temp1.end_date=temp2.date where temp1.group_id=temp2.group_id and temp2.date='$curDate' and temp2.free_spots>0`

You can check after each query if there were 0 rows updated. If they were, you're done and you can break the while loop.

Comment: This makes me feel the solution is better placed on the application side (Rails 3.x) instead of MySQL.

Comment: Also, selecting only records with free_spots > 0 into the second temp table will merge all begin/end ranges for that group. For example free spots batch [1,2,2,1,0,0,1,2,1] will be inserted as [1,2,2,1,1,2,1], thereby losing edge information from the center... Or I must have totally misunderstood you...

Answer (score -1):

this works on sql server (if i understood your question correctly). It should work on mysql as well:

select a.group_id, a.min_date, b.max_date from (
select s1.group_id, min(s1.date) min_date
from spots s1
group by s1.group_id) a
inner join
(select group_id, max(date) max_date from spots group by group_id) b
on a.group_id = b.group_id

Comment: This will give max 1 begin/end combo for each group. Consider batch of free spots [1,2,2,1,0,0,1,2,1]. This should obviously be [1,2,2,1] and [1,2,1] for the same group. 2 records.